# lua variables scope

Tags: variables, scope, lua, global-variables

I am aware there are other similar topics but could not find an straight answer for my question.

Suppose you have a function such as:

```
function aFunction()
  local aLuaTable = {}
  if (something) then
     aLuaTable = {}
  end
end
```

For the aLuaTable variable inside the if statement, it is still local right?. Basically what I am asking is if I define a variable as local for the first time and then I use it again and again any number of times will it remain local for the rest of the program's life, how does this work exactly?.

Additionally I read this definition for Lua global variables:

> Any variable not in a defined block is said to be in the global scope.
>   Anything in the global scope is accessible by all inner scopes.

What is it meant by not in a defined block?, my understanding is that if I "declare" a variable anywhere it will always be global is that not correct?.

Sorry if the questions are too simple, but coming from Java and objective-c, lua is very odd to me.

Comment: Not had a hell of a lot of XP with lua, but as far as I know the variable will be in scope inside that function - it will be out of scope outside of the function. Any variables declared outside of a function body (a defined block) are deemed to be in global scope and are accessible from anywhere in that lua script

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> "Any variable not in a defined block is said to be in the global scope."

This is simply wrong, so your confusion is understandable. Looks like you got that from the user wiki. I just updated the page with the correction information:

Any variable that's not defined as `local` is global.

> my understanding is that if I "declare" a variable anywhere it will always be global

If you don't define it as `local`, it will be global. However, if you then create a `local` with the same name, it will take precedence over the global (i.e. Lua "sees" locals first when trying to resolve a variable name). See the example at the bottom of this post.

> If I define a variable as local for the first time and then I use it again and again any number of times will it remain local for the rest of the program's life, **how does this work exactly?**

When your code is compiled, Lua tracks any local variables you define and knows which are available in a given scope. Whenever you read/write a variable, if there is a local in scope with that name, it's used. If there isn't, the read/write is translated (at compile time) into a table read/write (via the table _ENV).

```
local x = 10 -- stored in a VM register (a C array)
y = 20       -- translated to _ENV["y"] = 20

x = 20       -- writes to the VM register associated with x
y = 30       -- translated to _ENV["y"] = 30

print(x)     -- reads from the VM register
print(y)     -- translated to print(_ENV["y"])
```

Locals are lexically scoped. Everything else goes in `_ENV`.

```
x = 999

do -- create a new scope
    local x = 2
    print(x)      -- uses the local x, so we print 2
    x = 3         -- writing to the same local
    print(_ENV.x) -- explicitly reference the global x our local x is hiding
end

print(x) -- 999
```

Comment: Just a note that `_ENV` is Lua 5.2 only. In Lua 5.1 (and before), globals are stored in `_G` (in reality it is a bit more complicated than that, you can change the environment of a function, etc.).

Comment: I considered mentioning _G (which is the global state in 5.1 and the default value for _ENV in 5.2), but I figured that would just be confusing. 5.2 is the latest version so I went with _ENV. All the information about scope is the same except that in 5.1 the _ENV references would be _G references.

Comment: Hi @Mud, sorry for butting in. I have a question based on this confusion. I have a nested `if`. I have a variable inside the second `if` layer that I want to use in the first layer. Do I have to resort to global variable, or is there some ways to use it with local? I have submitted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855258/using-local-variable-outside-its-chunk-in-lua

Answer (score 4):

> For the aLuaTable variable inside the if statement, it is still local right?

I don't understand how you're confused here; the rule is the exact same as it is for Java. The variable is still within scope, so therefore it continues to exist.

A `local` variable is the equivalent of defining a "stack" variable in Java. The variable exists within the block scope that defined it, and ceases to exist when that block ends.

Consider this Java code:

```java
public static void main()
{
  if(...)
  {
    int aVar = 5; //aVar exists.
    if(...)
    {
      aVar = 10; //aVar continues to exist.
    }
  }

  aVar = 20; //compile error: aVar stopped existing at the }
}
```

A "global" is simply any variable name that is *not* local. Consider the equivalent Lua code to the above:

```
function MyFuncName()
  if(...) then
    local aVar = 5 --aVar exists and is a local variable.

    if(...) then
      aVar = 10 --Since the most recent declaration of the symbol `aVar` in scope
                --is a `local`, this use of `aVar` refers to the `local` defined above.
    end
  end

  aVar = 20 --The previous `local aVar` is *not in scope*. That scope ended with
            --the above `end`. Therefore, this `aVar` refers to the *global* aVar.
end
```

What in Java would be a compile error is perfectly valid Lua code, though it's probably not what you intended.